# need help custom marshaling..?

Tags: c#, interop, pinvoke, dllimport

i need help about custom marshaling..i have a native DLL..the parameters of the some DLL functions is defined with unsigned char*

for example;

```
typedef short apiStatus;
    apiStatus __declspec(dllexport) __stdcall DrfGetFirmwareVersion (HANDLE hCom, unsigned char *major,unsigned char *minor, unsigned char ReaderAddr = 0xff);
```

the documentation that i have describing the arguments of the function as follows;

Input parameter：

- hCom－Serial port handle
- major－main version No. of firmware program
- minor－subversion No. of firmware program
- ReaderAddr－ reader address, for fixed reader RS485 net application, default value “0XFF”(not applicable for handheld and module)

how can i declare this function into C#..??

Any help at all would be really appreciated

Answer (score 1):

If this DLL is really, really old (back when char was still unsigned) then it could be returning strings.  That's pretty unlikely though, just declare them as out byte:

```
[DllImport("blah.dll")]
private static extern noidea DrfGetFirmwareVersion(IntPtr handle, 
   out byte major, out byte minor, byte address);
```

Where "noidea" presumably is void or some kind of int error code.  Another thing to fret about is the DllImport.CallingConvention property, it could be Cdecl.  Use that when you get a MDA warning about a stack imbalance.  And don't forget to set your project's Platform Target to x86 or it will bomb on 64-bit operating systems.

Comment: thanks for the feedback..i have set the platform target to x86 like you said..another problem is the documentation explains a little things for the functions..sometimes i couldn't determine what i should do..the SDK of the device containsa lib file..i opened the lib with an editör and i encountered decorated names.i undecorated these decorated names with undname.exe..the results as follows; undname ?DrfGetFirmwareVersion@@YGFPAXPAE1E@Z---->>>>short __stdcall DrfGetFirmwareVersion(void*, unsigned char*, unsigned char*, unsigned char)

Comment: P.S."*" isn't seen the first parameter of the function..it could be as follows; void*

Comment: You'll need to use the DllImport.ExactSpelling property in your declaration.

Comment: i used it as follows; ExactSpelling=false and charset=charset.Ansi

Comment: Oops, I meant EntryPoint.  Sorry.

Comment: ok..i used as follows---->>>            [DllImport("DrfApiV10.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall,CharSet=CharSet.Ansi,EntryPoint="DrfGetFirmwareVersion", ExactSpelling=false)]

Comment: or instead of the function name i used the ordinal as follows--->>> [DllImport("DrfApiV10.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall,CharSet=CharSet.Ansi,EntryPoint="#12", ExactSpelling=false)]

Comment: or like this--->>> [DllImport("DrfApiV10.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall,CharSet=CharSet.Ansi,EntryPoint="?DrfGetFirmwareVersion@@YGFPAXPAE1E@Z", ExactSpelling=false)] ???

Comment: ExactSpelling=true.  Use Dumpbin.exe /exports on the DLL to find the real export names.  What is the error you get?  Also, you should have linked your MSDN forum thread.

Comment: ok..ExactSpelling=true.i have used Dumpbin.exe /exports on the DLL to find the real export names like you said. i know the ordinal of the function from there.yes i have been writing MSDN forum and i think you are a MVP on MSDN forum. what i try to do is to import the DLL into C#.it's for my graduation thesis..i'm not sure whether i marshal data types truely or not..

Comment: I'll twist your arm one more time: what is the error you get?

Comment: sorry..i'm not getting any error at the moment.. because what i do is to write the managed signatures for the functions..i haven't used the imported functions yet :S i have't sent any data to the function yet..

Comment: Sigh.  Well, you got more than enough info to troubleshoot it when you do.

Comment: ok i will do..after then can i continue this thread ?? thank you for your feedbacks and patience..

Answer (score 0):

i have used overloed for the default parameter(VS2005).i have imported the function as follows;

```
public class sDrfGetFirmwareVersion
        {
            //apiStatus __declspec(dllexport) __stdcall DrfGetFirmwareVersion (HANDLE hCom, unsigned char *major,unsigned char *minor, unsigned char ReaderAddr = 0xff);

            [DllImport("DrfApiV10.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall,CharSet=CharSet.Ansi,EntryPoint="DrfGetFirmwareVersion", ExactSpelling=false)]
            public static extern short DrfGetFirmwareVersion(IntPtr hCom, out byte major, out byte minor,byte ReaderAddr);
            public static short DrfGetFirmwareVersion(IntPtr hCom, out byte major,out byte minor)
              {
                  return DrfGetFirmwareVersion(hCom, out major,out minor, 0xff);
              }
        }
```

can you verify me please ??